# How to have two buttons in a same form to do different actions in ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a form, which take name from form and it sends to javascript codes and show in php by Ajax. these actions are done with clicking by submit button, I need to have another button, as review in my main page. how can I address to ajax that in process.php page have "if isset(submit)" or "if isset(review)"? 
I need to do different sql action when each of buttons are clicked. 
how can I add another button and be able to do different action on php part in process.php page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({
            debug: false,

            submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
      <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
    <div id="results"><div>
</body>
```

**process.php:**

```
<?php

    print "<br>Your name is <b>".$_POST['name']."</b> ";
?>
```

Comment: Don't use submit button  ,,Use two buttons,,, and trigger a function when clicked,,,the first will do some action and the anther will do anther action...

Comment: I also used a button like this, but it does not read the value of my button. <input type="image" name="accept" id="accept<?php echo $y; ?>" value="<?php echo $y ?>" src="accept.png">

Comment: okey then do check the nunespascal post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a button and an onclick handler for it.

Html:

```
<input type="button" id="review" value="Review"/>
```

Js:

```
$("#review").click(function(){
            var myData = $("#myform").serialize() + "&review=review";
            $.post('process.php', myData , function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        );
```

Since you have set a variable review here, you can use it to know that is call has come by clicking the review button.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and great reply!:)

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event handlers to the buttons' click events instead of the form's submit event.

Use the different event handler functions to add different pieces of extra data to the data object you pass to the ajax method.